In a Visual Studio VB.Net project, how can SQL connection parameters be saved for repeated use?
When working with SQL files in a VB.Net project, how can the connection parameters be saved for easier development?
There are SQL files in the project, to hold queries for use in the app. When one of the files is opened for editing & testing, the credentials & properties must be entered again - every time!
See screenshot below.
Anything in the Connect and Advanced Properties windows is lost each time the file is closed. The credentials are very long, so they must be copied & pasted, and some connection properties need to be set. To redo these every time is annoying & inconvenient.
How can the credentials & properties be saved in the project? (if possible)
Sidenote: I do understand credentials should not be hard-coded into the project, so that need not be discussed. This is just for development, and eventually I will toughen it up so the credentials will not be in the project.


"Anything in the Connect and Advanced Properties windows is lost each time the file is closed" - I don't have that problem: VS remembers my SQL Server connection-history just fine. Also, look for the "Pin" icon too.

...are you using the Server Explorer window? If not, you should be.

@Dai I have experimented in multiple ways & found the connection is always lost when the SQL file is closed, and when re-opened, the server, un, and pw must be re-entered, as described in the op. Using the Server Explorer makes no difference. Which pin are you referring to? The pin on the code window or Server Explorer.? I find pinning either of these makes no difference.

Would someone please explain the vote to close?

Consider using SQL Server Object Explorer.


I've tried. It makes no difference in this case. The connection is always lost when the SQL file is closed, and must be re-entered each time it is re-opened for editing & testing.

Look at the History tab in connect window and see if there are connection records in it.
